# Display Google AdSense ads to search engine traffic using html javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am using below PHP code for Displaying AdSense Ads only for search engine visitor.

But now I need HTML/JavaScript Code for Displaying Ads on search engine visitor.

I'm trying to create HTML/JavaScript code, but failed.

Can I modify/create this HTML/JavaScript code?

Have any solution? or Have any HTML/JavaScript code?

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$my_domain = "example.com";
$search_engines = "google|yahoo|bing|altavista|digg";
$pattern = "((http(s)?://)(\w+?\.)?(?!{$my_domain})({$search_engines}))";
if (preg_match("/{$search_engines}/i", $referrer) != false) {
echo <<<END
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
/* xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xx xxxxxx */
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = xxx;
google_ad_height = xxx;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
END;
} else {
// Show something to visitors not referred by a search engine
}
?>
```

Please help me, Sir.

Comment: Hello, Sir. Any one see this post?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit stupid, but you definetely can translate it to js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer.match(/google|yahoo|bing|altavista|digg/)) {

google_ad_client = "xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
/* xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xx xxxxxx */
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = xxx;
google_ad_height = xxx;

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", src);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
} else {
// Show something to visitors not referred by a search engine
}
</script>
```